# How to save a model, update the PK if it saves correctly

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Say I have a model like:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String)
```

I am using slick 3 so I have all Table defined etc.

My question is, I want to save a user, and then update the id to the newly inserted PK value from postgresql.

I want to re-use this pattern in my entire Data Layer, so if it can be extracted out to a function that would be better.

So I want to do this:

1. save the model
2. update the id with the newly inserted ID primary key value
3. throw an exception if it didn't save

How can i do this with slick 3.x ?

```
def save(user: User):User = {
  // (users returning users.map(_.id)) ??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], name: String)

def save(user: User)(implicit session:Session): User = {
    (users returning users.map(_.id) into ((user,id) => user.copy(id=Some(id)))) 
     += User(None, "mgosk")
}
```

There is relevant documentation page:

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#inserting

Comment: But if the id is less than 0 or -1, it should throw an exception if the db failed to insert the row.